# How can I convert a working regular expression in regex101 to Coldfusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion

[https://regex101.com/r/qNDKIh/1/][1]

How can I convert a working regular expression in regex101 to Coldfusion REMatchNoCase
[1]: https://regex101.com/r/qNDKIh/1/

`Coldfusion Code`

```
<cfset VinDetail = ReMatchNoCase("^([A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]{3})([A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]{5})([0-9X])([A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9])([A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9])([A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]{6})$", "1G1PA5SH9D7126083") />

<cfdump var="#VinDetail#">
```

Getting `Malformed regular expression` error

Regex101 output

```
Full match  0-17    1G1PA5SH9D7126083
Group `wmi` 0-3 1G1
Group `vds` 3-8 PA5SH
Group `check`   8-9 9
Group `vis` 9-17    D7126083
Group `year`    9-10    D
Group `plant`   10-11   7
Group `seq` 11-17   126083
```

Comment: Try without named capturing groups and `\d`: `<cfset VinDetail = ReMatchNoCase("^([A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]{3})([A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]{5})([0-9X])([A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9])([A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9])([A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]{6})$", VinString[1]) />`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew when I tried your code the error is gone but the result is just the input string.

Comment: What version of CF are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single result matching the input string is 'correct' - because `ReMatch()` only returns matches, and that is the actual match. If you want to return the capture groups then you can use `ReFind()` with `returnsubexpressions=true`, eg:

```
<cfset VinDetail2 = ReFindNoCase("^([A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]{3})([A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]{5})([0-9X])(([A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9])([A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9])([A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]{6}))$", "1G1PA5SH9D7126083", 1,true,'ALL') />
<cfdump var="#VinDetail2[1].MATCH#" />
<cfdump var="#VinDetail2#" />
```

[image: ReFindNoCase()-full-result]

https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=e4d3f15a-bd35-4a70-b806-3eec7a1fdf47/a8e67f20-a3ec-4d8d-9c0b-d4108a6aaea2/a2d7b829-36ba-4f55-9271-4aec369143cb.cfm

Comment: I learned so much from your answer. Thank you!
I can now use regex101 and use directly in CF. 
First time I see the power of ReFindNoCase. I have Perl background and understand the power of regex but never have really used complex regex in CF.